# How to resolve coreferences for a specific Noun phrase in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a series of rather large text files and am looking to resolve references in each file for a specific noun phrase eg. 'Harry Potter'

I wouldn't want to run the the pipeline in full for every single possibility of reference resolution as that would take far far too long.

Thanks very much!

Here is what I have so far...

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // SET INPUT AND OUTPUT FILES
    FileOutputStream xmlOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("nlp.xml"));
    String input_filename = "weblink_text.txt";
    String file_contents = IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(input_filename);

    //SET PROPERTIES
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, cleanxml, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");

    // ANNOTATE AND OUTPUT
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(file_contents);

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);

    System.out.println("Completed");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you only care about the co-reference resolution of pronominal antecedents, I would recommend checking out David Bamman's [book-nlp](https://github.com/dbamman/book-nlp).

It does very fast coref for novel-length texts, but only for pronominal antecedents (which are probably what you are most interested in anyways).

You can then read in the `.tokens` file and to build your own coreference graph.

2) If you really need to resolve coref for more than that, try setting the `dcoref.maxdist` parameter to prevent it from looking back to chapter 1 for material from chapter 20, for instance. I would then save some version of your annotated text (serialized, for instance) to load later so that you don't have to keep running this.

[edit]
3) In the relatively near future, there will be a new coref system (`hcoref`) in the Stanford CoreNLP build (https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/hcoref) that is based off of `depparse`, which is very much faster. I've been running that on 100 - 500 sentence-long chunks of text for a whole novel and that's been working for me. (there isn't yet an equivalent in `hcoref` to `dcoref.maxdist`)

Another note: if the parsing time is also prohibitively expensive, try setting `parse.maxlen`.

Comment: You're right in that I'm interested in pronominal antecedents...thanks for the link...I will certainly check it out

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a full coreference analysis is required to get any usable annotations for a particular noun phrase. (Without a full analysis resolving tough anaphora like pronouns would be impossible.)

The best I can recommend is that you do processing in small blocks which are fairly "independent" in terms of coreferences (e.g., chapters of a book).

Comment: I looked into reference resolution i.e. how it's actually handled and you're absolutely right. Saved me a whole load of time looking for a solution that does not exist, Thanks!